# Always return a Count? Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have some data like this

```
1 Red 2018-02-01
2 Red 2018-02-01
3 Red 2018-02-01
4 Blue 2018-02-01
5 Red 2018-02-02
5 Blue 2018-02-03
```

I want to get the total count per day per color so that would be something like this.

```
Select Count(Color) as count, color, myDate from colors
where color in ('red', 'blue') 
group by myDate , color
```

That should get me something like

```
3 red 2018-02-01
1 blue 2018-02-01
1 red 2018-02-02
1 blue 2018-02-03
```

How what I really want is this

```
3 red 2018-02-01
1 blue 2018-02-01
1 red 2018-02-02
0 blue 2018-02-02 <---- I want to know there was 0 blue on this day
1 blue 2018-02-03
0 red 2018-02-03 <----- I want to know there was 0 red on this day.
```

Is there a simple way to get this result back? I always need to see whatever is in the `in` clause. If I added something else I would need to see 3 colors per day.

Edit

Hopefully this makes it more clearer

Table

```
Id (int) - Pk
UserId (int)
Activity (varchar(20))
dDate (datetime)
```

Data

```
1 123 'Visited Home Page' 2018-02-23 05:15:14
2 123 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-23 04:15:15
3 456 'Visited Home Page' 2018-02-23 04:15:16
4 456 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-23 04:15:15
5 456 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-24 04:15:15
```

Expected Result

```
Count, Activity, dDate
2 'Visited Home Page' 2018-02-23
2 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-23
1 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-24
0 'Visited Home Page' 2018-02-24

SELECT Count(Activity) as Count, Activity,  Date(dDate) as d FROM myTable
WHERE Activity IN('Visited Home Page', 'Visited Page 1') AND 
DATE(dDateTime) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31'
GROUP BY Date(dDate), Activity

Current Result

    Count, Activity, dDate
    2 'Visited Home Page' 2018-02-23
    2 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-23
    1 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-24
```

Since no user went to the home page nothing was recorded. However I need to always have a result for everything that 
I put in my where clause.

if I added another one 'Visted Page 2' then the results should be

```
Count, Activity, dDate
2 'Visited Home Page' 2018-02-23
2 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-23
0 'Visited Page 2' 2018-02-23

1 'Visited Page 1' 2018-02-24
0 'Visited Home Page' 2018-02-24
0 'Visited Page 2' 2018-02-24
```

If nothing happened on that day I probably can get away with not bringing back any results. Though I would like to see how it would be done.

Comment: Have you considered changing your application logic to go through the dates in question and produce a count of zero when there is no row for the given colour/date?

Comment: I have, just wondering how hard it would be to do in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply left join the color, myDate result with the count result eg:

```
select distinct a.color, a.myDate , ifnull(t.num_color,0)
from colors a
left join ( 
  select color, myDate, count(*) num_color
  from colors
  group by color, myDate
) t on t.color= a.color AND t.myDate = a.myDate
```

eg for a between  clause  you could

```
select distinct a.color, a.myDate , ifnull(t.num_color,0)
from colors a
left join ( 
  select color, myDate, count(*) num_color
  from colors
  group by color, myDate
) t on t.color= a.color AND t.myDate = a.myDate 
        and date(a.myDate) between ( '2017-01-01') and ('2018-02-23')
```

and looking to your updated  question sample

you could use a sublect with the count for join the distinct activity and ddate

```
select distinct m.activity, date(m.dDate)
from my_table m
left join  (
  select activity,  date(dDate), count(*) as my_count 
  from my_table 
  group by activity,  date(dDate) as my_date
) t on t.activity = m.activity and date(m.dDate) = t.my_date
```

Comment: hey, I am having a problem with your code. I do see you have a typo with t.nyDate, but even when I fix it I still get an syntax error. Something with the date, when I remove it all is well.

Comment: answer  updated .. type and error  .. removed (missed  and)

Comment: Thanks, that works. I am working on incorpoating back my where clause and I actually have a date clause as well. like where myDate between '' and ''.  However the part I am stuck on right now is that myDate has time parts which I don't want. so I am trying to Date(myDate) but that is not working to well.

Comment: show me  tha table schema a proper data sample . your actual sql code and the exact epected  result

Comment: but remember that using a left join you should not  add  a where clause but add  the condition to the ON clause

Comment: answer  udpated  with  a suggestion

Comment: ok, I will update my post with a more complete schema. As still not getting it.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to do it in code as it just made more sense to me, if that turns out to slow I will revisit your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If this has to be done for 2 colors only, the easiest way is conditional aggregation with `union all`.

```
Select sum(Color='red') as count, 'red' as color, myDate
from colors 
group by myDate 
union all
Select sum(Color='blue') as count, 'blue' as color, myDate
from colors 
group by myDate
```

The other option is to generate all colors for each date with a cross join and count.

```
Select count(t.color), c.color, d.myDate
from (select distinct color from colors) c
cross join (select distinct myDate from colors) d
left join colors t on t.color=c.color and t.myDate=d.myDate 
group by c.color, d.myDate
```

If it is okay to have all counts on one row, use conditional aggregation.

```
select sum(color='red') as red,sum(color='blue') as blue,myDate
from colors
group by myDate
```

Edit: Based on OP's question update

```
select a.activity,d.dDate,count(t.dDate)
from (select distinct activity from t) a
cross join (select distinct date(dDate) as dDate from t) d
left join t on t.activity=a.activity and date(t.dDate)=d.dDate 
and d.dDate >= '2018-02-01' and d.dDate < '2018-03-01'
group by a.activity,d.dDate
```

Comment: This would still not show counts of zero on dates where no rows exist for the given colour.

Comment: I meant for the case where there are no rows of either colour on the given date. Although maybe that's not a concern for the OP.

Comment: How does the where in clause fit in with your second solution, I will have more than 2 colors. I will have 6+.